# Comparison between several dates times

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

My requirements:

- if the time is between 19:30:00 and 08:00:00 echo `10`
- otherwise echo `3`

How should I change my code so it meets these requirements?

DEMO: https://3v4l.org/tpauu

```
<?php

//$today_dt = new DateTime(date("H:i:s"));
//$today_dt = new DateTime(date("01:00:00")); **** Different result!!
$today_dt = new DateTime(date("01:00:00")); //**** Different result!!
$expire_dt1 = new DateTime(date("19:30:00"));
$expire_dt2 = new DateTime(date("08:00:00"));
if ($today_dt < $expire_dt1 && $today_dt < $expire_dt2){
    $DateEnd = strtotime(date('10:30:00'));
    echo '10';
}else{
    $DateEnd = strtotime(date('H:i:s')." +3 hour");
    echo '3';
}
echo '<br>'.date('H:i:s',$DateEnd);

?>
```

Comment: Change `$today_dt < $expire_dt1 && $today_dt < $expire_dt2` to `$today_dt > $expire_dt1 && $today_dt < $expire_dt2`

Answer (score 0):

At the start of new day...
`$today_dt = new DateTime(date("01:00:00"));` comes first then `$expire_dt2 = new DateTime(date("08:00:00"));` and then `$expire_dt1 = new DateTime(date("19:30:00"));` so I think you have to make proper comparision.
Just check it 
`var_dump($today_dt<$expire_dt1);
var_dump($today_dt<$expire_dt2);` Both gives true and `var_dump($expire_dt1>$expire_dt2); also gives true.So makes the following comparison ..hope it will works..`

```
//$today_dt = new DateTime(date("H:i:s"));
//$today_dt = new DateTime(date("01:00:00")); **** Different result!!
$today_dt = new DateTime(date("01:00:00")); //**** Different result!!
$expire_dt1 = new DateTime(date("19:30:00"));
$expire_dt2 = new DateTime(date("08:00:00"));
// var_dump($today_dt<$expire_dt1);
// var_dump($today_dt<$expire_dt2);
// var_dump($expire_dt1>$expire_dt2);
if ($today_dt > $expire_dt1 && $today_dt < $expire_dt2){
    $DateEnd = strtotime(date('10:30:00'));
    echo '10';
}else{
    $DateEnd = strtotime(date('H:i:s')." +3 hour");
    echo '3';
}
echo '<br>'.date('H:i:s',$DateEnd);
```

See more here http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php